# Двойная интерпретация в шаблонах Django

Tags: python, django

Язык шаблона Django - это полноценный язык, который интерпретируется Питоном. Следовательно, в процессе создания страницы HTML из шаблона Django происходит две ступени интерпретации:

1. в скрипте (py),
2. в шаблоне (html).

Если страница сложная (с точки зрения интерпретации), то время ее генерации может быть очень велико.

Возникают два связанных вопроса.

1. Как решается эта проблема? Какие могут быть пути оптимизации по скорости работы для Django?
2. Какие компилируемые аналоги Django существуют?

Answer (score 1):

1. использование сторонних шаблонизаторов например [cheetah](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/django/49636/) или кэширование шаблонов с помощью django.

Comment: или [jinja2][1]


  [1]: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Ну первое что можно сделать, это прямо настроить кеширование. 
Если объем данных большой и нужен полнотекстовый поиск или что то подобное, то можно поставить и настроить [link text](http://sphinxsearch.com/). Если непринципиально для поисковой оптимизации то можно еще отдельные части грузить динамически. Вообще много способов есть все убыстрить. Тут вопрос именно специфики проекта.